# MongoDb error: 'cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled'

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongock

I was using mongo in dev just fine, when deploying the app into test env I got this error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled' on server localhost:34653. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue"}
```

full stuck trace:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled' on server localhost:34653. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:303)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:450)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:218)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWriteCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:369)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWriteCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:360)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:284)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:277)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation$1.call(CreateIndexesOperation.java:177)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation$1.call(CreateIndexesOperation.java:172)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:530)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:492)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:172)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeCreateIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:886)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:869)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:864)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndex(MongoCollectionImpl.java:849)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase.createRequiredUniqueIndex(MongoSync4RepositoryBase.java:99)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase.ensureIndex(MongoSync4RepositoryBase.java:58)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase.initialize(MongoSync4RepositoryBase.java:43)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.core.driver.ConnectionDriverBase.initialize(ConnectionDriverBase.java:40)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.runner.core.executor.MigrationExecutor.initializationAndValidation(MigrationExecutor.java:225)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.spring.v5.core.SpringMigrationExecutor.initializationAndValidation(SpringMigrationExecutor.java:31)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.runner.core.executor.MigrationExecutor.executeMigration(MigrationExecutor.java:63)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.spring.v5.core.SpringMigrationExecutor.executeMigration(SpringMigrationExecutor.java:37)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.runner.core.executor.MongockRunnerBase.execute(MongockRunnerBase.java:53)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongock-spring-v5</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v3-driver</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

configuration:

```
@Bean
public MongockSpring5.MongockApplicationRunner mongockApplicationRunner(
    ApplicationContext springContext,
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    log.debug("Configuring Mongock");
    return MongockSpring5.builder()
        .setDriver(SpringDataMongoV3Driver.withDefaultLock(mongoTemplate))
        // package to scan for migrations
        .addChangeLogsScanPackage("ru.fabit.visor.config.dbmigrations")
        .setSpringContext(springContext)
        .setEnabled(true)
        .buildApplicationRunner();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf7u2.png)

i set command: mongod --journal
but the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, you should enable journaling on the server. Look [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-journaling/). Another option, don't configure `journal` in writeConcern (which is not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Mongock, by default, requires strong consistency(it's the only way to guarantee a change is only applied once). This means that MongoDB needs to have journalism enabled.

However, as said, that's the default configuration(and highly recommended for production), but you can relax it for specific scenarios, such as tests, where you may want to set up a MongoDB in memory(which by definition doesn't allow journalism).Take a look to the [Mongock documentation for MongoDB](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/driver/mongodb-sync/index.html#:%7E:text=%23-,Properties,-Property)